# pyqt5 QTreeWidget implement like filesystemmodel

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreewidget, qfilesystemmodel

I want to implement `filesystemmodel` with `QTreeWidget`.
I tried with `setModel(QFileSystemModel)` but it was private method so I can't use it, I think I should customize it.
I want to implement drag and drops of child node and create directory etc like filesystem model
Who did this do before? If so, Pls help me with the code.

Comment: use QTreeView .... + QFileSystemModel

Comment: Hey, I dont want to use filesystem. I just want to use custom tree that do like filesystem.

Comment: 1) What about QFileSystemModel is an option, the important thing about my previous comment is that you should use QTreeView since, as I pointed out in my related answer, QTreeWidget has a read-only model unlike QTreeView that if you can set any model (either QFileSystemModel or your custom model), 2) If you consider my action to be against SO rules then please report it to a moderator.

Comment: Of course I know about filesystem model, but it support only for real file system. I want to  get customized tree widget

Comment: You point out that you already have a custom model (it is understood that it is a class based on QAbstractItemModel) with your comment: *I tried with setModel(QFileSystemModel) but it was private method*, and that you cannot place it in a QTreeWidget since that class does not allow to set models so I point again: use QTreeView

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts in SO? I find it strange that 2 users ask the same thing.

Comment: Who is he? same question? What do you mean?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62481560/combine-qtreewidget-and-filesystemmodel-pyqt5

Comment: He is from india and memeber 3 years ago. I just member from 2 months

Comment: mmm, it is common for a user to create accounts later to get points and have more privileges like posting more questions. Why do you say he is from India?

Comment: Oh , I can't understand why you are so bad for me. I didn't do any harm action to you before. Please forgive me. I am a honest man. I just guessed from his name so he is india